# Do web workers work properly if the client only has a one core CPU?

Tags: multithreading, web-worker

Pure curiosity, I'm just wondering if there is any case where a webworker would manage to execute a separate thread if only one thread is available in the CPU, maybe with some virtualization, using the GPU?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the Web Workers framework, but in general, the number of threads in a program is not limited by the number of available processors. Multi-threaded programs were a thing before multi-CPU systems were a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be two premises behind your question: firstly, that web workers use threads; and secondly that multiple threads require multiple cores. But neither is really true.

On the first: there’s no actual requirement that web workers be implemented with threads. User agents are free to use processes, threads or any “equivalent construct” [see the web worker specification]. They could use multitasking within a single thread if they wanted to. Web worker scripts are run concurrently but not necessarily parallel to browser JavaScript.

On the second: it’s quite possible for multiple threads to run on a single CPU. It works a lot like concurrent async functions do in single threaded JavaScript.

So yes, in answer to your question: web workers do run properly on a single core client. You will lose some of the performance benefits but the code will still behave as it would in a multi core system.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're talking about the concept / type "worklets" rather than web workers. 1.9 "Web workersThis section defines an API for background threads in JavaScript." https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#structure-of-this-specification